# No date/time in Select statement, getting: Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, smalldatetime

I have the following select statement

```
 SELECT Distinct lastname, firstname, UserName, r.name as 'Role', ug.name AS 'UserGroup'
```

and the following where statement

```
where userid = 894 and (EndDate > '2022-05-11 00:00:00' or endDate = 'NULL')
```

Getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

How do I fix this without entering a date/time in the Select statement?

Comment: Use am unambiguous format for your datetime literal; either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`.

Comment: `endDate = 'NULL'`? That isn't going to work. You want `IS NULL`.

Comment: What is the data type of `EndDate`? Why would it ever be equal to the _string_ `'NULL'`? Did you mean `or endDate IS NULL`?